# Ocean API - unit system

Tags: eclipse, ocean, petrel

Is it correct to say that the unit system from Ocean API for simulation results (cumulative oil production, gas, water, etc) is always SI unit system regardless the unit system choosen by the user in eclipse input file and/or Petrel interface?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use the unit conversion utilities in `PetrelUnitSystem` when interacting with the user interface.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you read data using the Ocean API the values of the data are returned in SI units. You can use PetrelUnitSystem to convert them to display units when you present them to the user in some UI. You also use it to convert data you are acquiring in display units to SI units before you write them to the project.